# closing jsp window

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have a jsp page that checks a query if the answer is true the program goes to a servlet page
otherwise the program continue as planned my question is:
if i do go to the servlet page how can i close the original jsp page from the
servlet

Answer (score 2):

It's true that you can close a window using JavaScript's `window.close()`, but the window will only be closed when the window is opened by *your* application using `window.open()` and **not** when it is opened by the enduser itself (e.g. by a link, form submit, bookmark, etc).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using javascript, and make them execute when your condition satisfy

Answer (score 1):

You can not close browser window from the servlet.

But you can close window using javascript.

For example write something like:

```
<body onLoad="closeWindow(<% bean.isCloseWindow %>)">
```

And in javascript function "closeWindow" do something like this:

```
function closeWindow(ifClose) {
if (ifClose) {
window.close();
}
}
```